# DELL Latitude E5500 BIOS Error : No boot sector detected on USB during the Ubuntu installation

Tags: dell, external-hdd, bios

I am trying to install the Ubuntu in external HDD (Transcend Store Jet USB 3.0 1 TB) using the Laptop Latitude E5500 (of course old model).

Laptop is able to detect the Boot device from Pen drive (16 GB Transcend USB 2.0). When i install the Ubuntu in the External HDD, BIOS is giving error message as 'No Boot sector on USB' (if i remember the exact sentence).

I have tried the below ways.
I have 2 pen drives (16 GB USB 2.0), one laptop(E5500), one external HDD(1 TB USB 3.0).

**Option 1**:

**Step 1**:- Created the Boot-able Linux on PEN Drive using the 'Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2.exe'.

**Step 2**:- Restarted the PC and Ubuntu is running successfully with Linux in Pen drive.

**Step 3**:- Install Linux in External HDD (Order of partition ('/boot' : 500 MB; '/' : 120 GB; Swap : 10 GB)). Installation success.

**Step 4**:- Restart PC, Removed the Pen drive and select Boot from USB mass storage. Error '**No Boot sector on USB**' ------ No success.

**Option 2**:

**Step 1**:- Created the Boot-able Linux on PEN Drive 1 using the 'Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2.exe'. Restarted the PC and Ubuntu is running successfully with Linux in Pen drive 1.

**Step 2**:- Boot partition in Pen drive 2 ('/boot' :- 500 MB; remaining space of 16 GB as NTFS partition.) and Partitions ('\' : 120 GB; 'Swap area' : 10 GB) in External HDD. Installation success

**Step 3**:- Restart PC, Removed the Pen drive 1 and select Boot from USB mass storage. again Error '**boot sector (BOOTMGR) not found. Press Alt+Ctrl+Delete to restart**' ------ No success. I think this error is from device Pen drive 2.

Is BIOS has problem of detecting the USB 3.0 HDD or it is not able to detect the large size HDD; i am not sure.

My BIOS version is A19.

Is there any way i can install Linux on Laptop (Latitude E5500). Laptop is running well with Windows 7.

**Note**: Please no suggestions on change of laptop. As this my Organisation laptop, in which i do not have any control.

I hope all of you have understood my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is the bios won't see 1TB. Plus your HDD may be USB 3.0 but you would only get the speeds of the USB 2.0 technology if that is what your computer has. Best bet if you want to run Ubuntu and cannot install on the internal HDD then get yourself a 64 GB flash drive and install on there.